# libgdx как сделать зацикливание меню

Tags: java, android, libgdx, прокрутка

Программист не может реализовать прокрутку меню по кругу.
Как в этом видео
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E_gKdIsD_kQSUHmgSbzonVLxINsHUAXz
«В libgdx нет для этого такого инструмента»
Подскажите, возможно ли в libgdx сделать прокрутку меню влево/вправо по кругу?

Comment: Этот инструмент называется "прямые руки" DD

Comment: ВНИМАНИЕ! Этот комментарий пишу в шутку, не рекомендую так делать!                       ----------------------------------------------------------------------                          Можно просто продублировать пункты меню 100 раз, и никто не доскролит до сааамого конца=)

Comment: @ДавидМанжула Ага while  зациклить

Comment: можно сделать всё на libgdx, если руки прямые